# ngx-bootstrap datepicker configuration issue

Tags: c#, angular

I am a starter of angular. I am trying to add ngx-bootstrap to my angular 6 project to add datepicker.After installation I put it in my System.js file like this

[image]

When i tried to run my application it gives errors of rxjs i.e `localhost:3000/node_modules/operators.js` NOT Found.
I read on github to update rxjs version but when i update my rxjs version to recent one my other reference of Observable & Subject broke.Kindly tell what is missed by me.
Thanks

Comment: Please post some relevant code so we can assist you - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I assume you want to import rxjs operators? In that case it's `import ... from 'rxjs/operators'`.

Comment: @shellNinja actually there is nothing wrong with my code as i only add reference of ngx-bootstrap using npm in my project. And when I rerun it gives following error
"http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/ 404 (Not Found)"
In my system.js I wrote

'ngx-bootstrap': 'npm:ngx-bootstrap'
Can you help me out how fix it?

Comment: Is this Angular or AngularJS? I've never had to edit a file named system.js for a project, ever. Regardless, that may be more suited to a different or updated question rather than solving in comments.